# How to manage JSON data in a Leaflet to control layer

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I want to add this json data connection to the map control.

This is my JSON data:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1234",
    "id_jenis": "15",
    "nama": "",
    "cabang": "01",
    "no_sp": "",
    "pelapor": "HERNI BUDIYATI",
    "alamat": "JL.SAMARINDA",
    "status_proses": null,
    "gps_lat": "-8.15901548898326",
    "gps_log": "114.33938219636661",
    "status": "0",
    "petugas_1": null,
    "tindakan": null,
    "tgl_tindakan": null,
    "keterangan": "PASANG BARU"
  },
  {
    "id": "1253",
    "id_jenis": "15",
    "nama": "",
    "cabang": "01",
    "no_sp": "",
    "pelapor": "AHMAD SULAIMAN",
    "alamat": "JL.BATUR",
    "status_proses": null,
    "gps_lat": "-8.20307616134188",
    "gps_log": "114.37318817745438",
    "status": "0",
    "petugas_1": null,
    "tindakan": null,
    "tgl_tindakan": null,
    "keterangan": "PASANG BARU"
  },
  {
    "id": "1264",
    "id_jenis": "15",
    "nama": "",
    "cabang": "01",
    "no_sp": "",
    "pelapor": "MASTIKAH",
    "alamat": "JL. KUTILANG",
    "status_proses": null,
    "gps_lat": "-8.244054483129496",
    "gps_log": "114.35282327992832",
    "status": "0",
    "petugas_1": null,
    "tindakan": null,
    "tgl_tindakan": null,
    "keterangan": "PASANG BARU"
  }
]
```

and this is my HTML script:

```
init();
function init() {
url2 = "urlfromjson";
var promise = $.getJSON(url2);
    promise.then(function(data) {
        var ob = L.layerGroup(data);
        pb = ob._layers;
        for (var i in pb){

            var lat= pb[i].gps_lat;
            var lng= pb[i].gps_log;
            var ps = L.marker([lat, lng]).addTo(map);;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you want to do, but from your code it looks like you want to add markers to your map based on coordinates in your JSON. Is that correct?

Comment: @TomazicM yeah right, I want to add coordinate markers to the map and can be adjusted via map control as desired.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "adjusted via map control"?